# Make a dialogue box pop up in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dialog

I'm working on a MVC4 project where I need to create a pop up notification when a user logs in if they have certain expired criteria. However, I actually have no idea what the best method for doing this might be. Some solutions I've found so far seem to recommend a jQuery, but as I'm unfamiliar with the use of them, I was hoping to avoid this method for now if possible - I'm looking for what could be considered a 'caveman' solution for this issue, so that I can better build upon it and develop an understanding, rather than trying to implement something far beyond my skills and digging a deeper hole for myself.

As I am most familiar with WinForms, I had originally hoped there was something similar to the MessageBox.Show capability. Sending the user to another View entirely is an option, but business logic dictates that a pop up with an 'OK' button to make it disappear would be cleaner.

Please let me know what your thoughts are or if I'm unclear about what I'm trying to achieve!

Comment: A pop-up box on the client side is going to require some kind of java-script solution, so this isn't really a C# question (or even an MVC question)

Comment: You are confusing client-side functionality with server-side functionality, which is what ASP.NET WebForms has trained a generation a developers to do.  Realize that ASP.NET MVC is a server-side framework for responding to HTTP requests, and not a client-side framework for building a UI.  The server only returns the client-side code, which is what you need to use to solve this problem.

Comment: I honestly hadn't even had my mind of the client/server side of things - was focused too much on "how can I get this done and out of the way." After a little bit of playing around in the code, I just did a redirect to a different view and that was way easier than I was originally expecting it to be, so it's problem solved anyway!